# Is it true that for every subset $A\subseteq\Bbb R$: $\Bbb R\sim A$ or $\Bbb R\sim \Bbb R\setminus A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering about exactly what is in the title:

> Is it true that for every subset $A\subseteq\Bbb R$: $$\Bbb R\sim A\text{ or }\Bbb R\sim \Bbb R\setminus A$$
>   where $\sim$ denotes equinumerosity

I would myself say this is the case, however I have not been able to prove this. I could however think of some cases that involve the continuum hypothesis in order to work, or isn't this the case?

Answer (score 2):

We use **Lemma 1**: If $U\cup V$ is infinite, then $|U\cup V|=\max(|U|,|V|)$.

Apply this to $A$ and $\mathbb R\setminus A$.

This does not require the continuum hypothesis, but it does require axiom of choice. Specifically, Lemma 1 follow from the fact that if $U$ is infinite then $|2\cdot U|=|U|$, which is often proven using Zorn's lemma, which is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice.